# onBoundsChange property not available. React, google maps

Tags: reactjs, google-maps

When using the `google-map-react` package I am not able to use the prop `onBoundsChanged`, getting the error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Readonly<Props>): GoogleMapReact', gave the following error.
    Type '{ children: Element; ref: any; bootstrapURLKeys: { key: string; }; defaultCenter: any; defaultZoom: any; onDrag: (map: any) => void; onBoundsChanged: (map: any) => void; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<GoogleMapReact> & Readonly<Props> & Readonly<...>'.
      Property 'onBoundsChanged' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<GoogleMapReact> & Readonly<Props> & Readonly<...>'.
```

This is my example code:

```
class Map extends Component<MapProps, MapState> {

render() {
        return (
        <div className="mapContainer">
            <GoogleMapReact ref={this.map}
            bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: "MY_API_KEY" }}
            defaultCenter={this.props.center}
            defaultZoom={this.props.zoom}
            onDrag = { this.handleMapDrag }
            onBoundsChanged = { ()=>{} }
            >
            <Marker
                lat={this.state.center.lat}
                lng={this.state.center.lng}
            />
            </GoogleMapReact>
        </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Any idea what might be wrong? I can use the onDrag prop without any problem. I have also tried with `onBoundsChange` without any luck.

Thanks.

Comment: I've removed your API key from your answer. Please don't share private API keys on public sites, and make sure you restrict them as per https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices#restrict_apikey

Comment: Also can you please provide a codesandbox or stackblitz so that we can reproduce this issue from our side?